# Custom directive hidden but code still runs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I have a custom directive which is sometimes hidden using ng-hide:

```
<my-custom-directive ng-show="vm.showBox"
    value="vm.objects"
></my-custom-directive>
```

A snippet from my custom directive code:

```
function myCustomDirective() {
    var directive = {
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        ///...
        scope: {
            value: '='
        }
    };
    return directive;

    function controller($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        ///...
        $scope.value.dates = $scope.value.dates || [];      
    }
}
```

The problem: even when the directive isn't supposed to be loaded/displayed (because `vm.showBox` is false), the custom directive's controller code runs and in such case it fails because `$scope.value` isn't passed (it's undefined there).

Why does the directive's controller code runs anyway, if the directive is hidden? I want to assume that if the directive is used, it's given valid parameters without having to check whether `$scope.value` is defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ng-show` controls visibility of element (change of css property `display`) but element still exists in DOM. to remove/create element you can use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`

Answer (score 0):

ng-show only controls display property of element. It does not prevent element to render in DOM. To prevent it you can use ng-if.

But the problem with ng-if is that according to condition every it destroy scope and creates new one.

To prevent this problem you should use ng-show.

In your case you can use watch expressin in your directive.

```html
<my-custom-directive ng-show="vm.showBox"
    value="vm.objects"
></my-custom-directive>
```

```js
function myCustomDirective() {
    var directive = {
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        ///...
        scope: {
            value: '='
        }
    };
    return directive;

    function controller($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        ///...

        var watchExpression = $scope.$watch('value', function(newValue, oldValue){
            if(newValue)
            {
                $scope.value.dates = $scope.value.dates || [];
                watchExpression(); //de-register watch expression
            }
        });
    }
}
```